# record audio from bluetooth headset using bluealsa on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, audio-recording, alsa

I am using onboard Bluetooth on Raspberry pi zero and connected a Bluetooth speaker which also has a mic. I want to record audio from this BT speaker mic.

I understand bluealsa command line can be used for this purpose, and also for playback of a .wav audio file.

I could not succeed with bluealsa sco profile to record audio. (OS: Dietpi)
The device is able to connect to pi, and can play wav files, 
using: **aplay -D bluealsa:DEV=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,PROFILE=a2dp  sample.wav**

However, with arecord, it says its recording, but doesn't record anything, also it doesn't throw any error.

using: **arecord -f cd -D bluealsa:DEV=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,PROFILE=sco test.wav**

Output: Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo

test.wav shows only 44 bytes on the system:

**-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     44 Jun  9 15:38 test.wav**

when I try to play the recorded file, its just noise.

Could anyone help? Is recording from BTspeakers even supported in bluealsa package itself?

Comment: same question but no answer yet:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=201101

Comment: @key_ After a lot of head scratching, I found what was missing. There is a key aspect going wrong under the hood. so, basically the bluealsa service need to be started with multiple profiles enabled like a2dp-source, a2dp-sink and hfp-ag, hsp-ag. pls see my answer for more details.

Comment: @key_ also, are you installing bluealsa with apt-get or you compiled it from sources. It looks like with apt-get, an older version of bluealsa gets installed, apparently which doesn't have audio recording functionalities implemented in it.

Comment: thank you for sharing. I gave up on this. Maybe I will try again in a view years.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said, after a lot of head scratching, found some key aspects are missing while bluealsa service is getting started.

1. By default, the bluealsa service is starting with only with "a2dp-source" profile. This is only for playback of audio. But for recording audio, it needs "a2dp-sink", "hfp-ag", and "hsp-ag" profiles.
2. Use below command if you are using any raspberry or ubuntu based distributions.
   "systemctl cat bluealsa"
   This shows the unit file for "bluealsa" service. it should have the below line for ExecStart.
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/bluealsa -p a2dp-sink -p a2dp-source -p hfp-ag -p hsp-ag

3.Usually what I have observed is with out any -p options passed to it. change the unit file and restart the service.
Note: whenever any systemctl unit files are changed, the below command must be executed to take changes into effect.

```
1. "systemctl daemon-reload"
2. systemctl restart bluealsa
```

4.Another thing to note is: using profile "sco" in asounrc file.

recording audio should work after these changes! This is what worked for me! after a long ordeal!